# I'm trying to make an interactive text game like but when I try the player input it says (Exception has occurred: CLR/System.FormatException) code>>

Tags: c#, debugging, game-development

```
using System;

namespace Coding_basics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = " To Infinity";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
           int decision  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered the program, press 1 to proceed or press 2 to leave");
            Console.ReadLine();
            if (decision == 1 )  { Console.WriteLine("Good luck...");
            } 
            if (decision == 2) { Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the text to come up and then be able to choose 1 or 2 to continue or close the game, please explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `Console.ReadLine()` that are not needed, you also declare and read `decision` to early. You can try the below:

```
using System;

namespace Coding_basics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "To Infinity";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered the program, press 1 to proceed or press 2 to leave");
            
            int decision  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            if (decision == 1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good luck...");
            }
            if (decision == 2)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: it could be `else if (decision == 2)`